# Do categories of bimodules have enough projectives?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, projective-module, bimodules

It is well-known and easy to prove (assuming the axiom of choice) that the category $R\text{-}\mathrm{Mod}$ has enough projectives for any ring $R$:
Let $M$ be any $R$-module, and let $P$ be the free left $R$-module with basis given by the set $M$.
Define a map $\pi:P\to M$ using the universal property of free objects by sending the basis element $m$ in the set $M$ to the corresponding element of the module $M$.
The module $P$ is free and therefore projective, and clearly $\pi$ is surjective.

Does the category $R\text{-}\mathrm{Mod}\text{-}S$ of $(R,S)$-bimodules have enough projectives?
It seems that the above argument doesn't generalize.
Does the category $R\text{-}\mathrm{Mod}\text{-}S$ even have free objects?
I'd love to see a proof, counterexample, or resource one way or the other.

Comment: A $(R,S)$-bimodule is the same as a left $R\otimes S^{op}$ module

Comment: Of course. Thanks! Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A $(R,S)$-bimodule is the same thing as left $R\otimes S^{op}$-module, so you have enough projectives, and in fact as you mentioned we have free objects.

Comment: Just a comment that the tensor is over $\mathbb{Z}$. Or, if both $R$ and $S$ are algebras over a common $k$, then we can take tensor over $k$.

Comment: I take that back... if you tensor over $k$ you impose an additional condition on your module; namely that the copy of $k$ acts the same way in $R$ as it does in $S$. (One could call such a thing a $(R,S)$-bimodule over $k$).

Comment: @equin : absolutely ! With this addendum, this is actually important (you could also say "bimodules in $k$-modules" )