# Is the category of bimodules over a ring an abelian category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

For any ring $R$ the category of right or left modules over $R$ is an abelian category. Is this also true for the category of $R$-$R$-bimodules?

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3129497/473276) fact might be helpful.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for pointing this out.